# Error with CharObjects in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

The following VBA code adds a ChartObject to sheet "Feuil1" but also returns a generic 1004 error (error defined by the object).

```
Sub test()

Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = Worksheets("Feuil1").ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)

End Sub
```

I do not understand the meaning of this message as the work is properly done, ie the ChartObject is created.

To investigate further, I decided to plot some data to this ch ChartObject. I took the VBA online help as example :

```
Sub test()

Dim ch As ChartObject
Set ch = Worksheets("Feuil1").ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)

ch.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("a1:a20"), _
gallery:=xlLine, Title:="New Chart"

End Sub
```

Once again I have the generic 1004 error message and the debugger shows that the error is caused by line `Set ch = Worksheets("Feuil1").ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)`. My cells A1 to A20 are filed with data so the problem is elsewhere.

Any idea for the origin of this error ?

Comment: it works correctly for me with Excel 2013, which version do you use? Do you have the same issue if you try it in other workbook / sheet name ... ?

Comment: I use Excel 2016... I tried with an other sheet name / workbook and the problem is still here.

Comment: Try this: `Worksheets("Feuil1").ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)` and then in the next line `Set ch = ActiveChart`. I guess you also need to declare it as `Chart` and not as `ChartObject`.

Comment: Thank you for your try but the error message remains the same.

Comment: Go back and test before you start naming objects. Try this first: Worksheets("Feuil1").ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250).Chart to see if the appendage 'Chart' is possible.

Comment: The code you propose makes the ChartObject appear in "Feuil1" (blank rectangle) but no Chart is embedded in the ChartObject. And I still get the 1004 error message. I guess the appendage 'Chart' cannot be done this way.

Comment: Works fine on my 2016. Open a blank workbook, change nothing and run `Set ch = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)`

Comment: Doing as you say I now have a more verbose error 1004: "specified dimensions are not valid for the type of graphic" (translated from french to english). However, the error message can also be the generic one if I apply the exactly same macro on another Excel worksheet. So, same code but different error messages.

Comment: Try adding a generic chartobject and then resize it